# Yii relation Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: yii, belongs-to, yii-relations

I've these tables

**estudiantes**

id_estudiante pk
nombre_estudiante

**evaluaciones**

id_evaluacion pk
evaluacion_estudiante
evaluacion_asignatura

**asignaturas**

id_asignatura pk
nombre_asignatura

in evaluaciones model relations

```
return array(
                'estudiantes'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Estudiantes', 'evaluacion_estudiante'),
        );
```

evaluaciones's _view file i have this

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->estudiantes->nombre_estudiante); ?>
```

and there is an error on that line, it seems to be a problem with relations.. but i cant solve it.

Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you are trying to echo something that doesn't exist.

The best way to get rid of this error is to check your value first before rendering it for output.

you can do:

```
if(!empty($data->estudiantes->nombre_estudiante))
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->estudiantes->nombre_estudiante); ?>
```

or using ternary:

```
<?php (!empty($data->estudiantes->nombre_estudiante)?
echo CHtml::encode($data->estudiantes->nombre_estudiante) : "null value"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if there's a row in table "evaluaciones" with null value in the field evaluacion_estudiante.

If so, you must check if $data->estudiantes is null before echo.